# Logica SMPP session.submitMulti(request);

Tags: smpp

im trying to send multiple messages by using "submitMulti( request );" method. Even though all the parameters are been correctly set, there is an error message in the console saying "Submit multi operation faild. java.lang.NullPointerException". Please I need a quick answer.
and here is my code.

```
        SubmitMultiSM request = new SubmitMultiSM();
        SubmitMultiSMResp response;

        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            request.addDestAddress(new DestinationAddress("94710486836"););
        }

        // set other values
        request.setServiceType("CMT");
        request.setSourceAddr("94115933333");
        request.setReplaceIfPresentFlag(replaceIfPresentFlag);
        request.setShortMessage("Test");
        request.setScheduleDeliveryTime(scheduleDeliveryTime);
        request.setValidityPeriod(validityPeriod);
        request.setEsmClass(esmClass);
        request.setProtocolId(protocolId);
        request.setPriorityFlag(priorityFlag);
        request.setRegisteredDelivery(registeredDelivery);
        request.setDataCoding(dataCoding);
        request.setSmDefaultMsgId(smDefaultMsgId);

        response = session.submitMulti(request);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using com.logica.smscsim.Simulator as your base? Full stacktrace will be helpful.

Comment: no Im not using the Simulator. Im trying with a provided Ip and a port. and It is working on sending single messages really fine.

Comment: did you got any success as I am in the same situation as you were?